# React/RCTBridge.h' file not found?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10.1

I create a react-native app. I added ibeacon manager using

```
npm install react-native-beacons-manager
react-native link react-native-beacons-manager
```

After that when ı run project on xcode 10.1 ı got 'React/RCTBridge.h file not found'
How can fix it?
[image]
Also when ı manage scheme show React(missing)[image] pop-up window when I try to add [image] shows this. When ı added react the ı got same error.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12042#issuecomment-275025960

Comment: Thanks @Jayraj ı can do it. And build success but when ı run app ı also got the same error. And xcode scheme shows React(Missing).

Comment: can you share screenshot of errors?

Comment: @Jayraj ı edited question. You can see.

Comment: ON XCODE

GO TO PRODUCT  --> SCHEME ---> MANAGE SCHEME

Then on Popup click on + and add react from dropdown list and then click ok

Comment: @AmardeepSingh thanks ı edited questions you can see. There is not any changing  when ı added react.

Comment: In terminal go to your project directory

1. Install Cocoa Pods
    sudo gem install cocoapods

2 In your Project Folder :
   cd ios
   pod install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terminal go to your project directory

1. Install Cocoa Pods 
   sudo gem install cocoapods

2 In your Project Folder: 
  cd ios pod install